# Line textbox HTML

Tags: html, css

I want to create a textbox like this:

[image]

It is just a line where you can input text. Is it possible to do this with css? or on bootstrap?

Comment: Why do people down vote questions like this. He/she is probably new to HTML/CSS and doesn't know. Sure he/she can Google this, but maybe he/she doesn't know what to Google.

Comment: Yes that's so true. I came to this question after typing something like 'input box line style css'. I'm one of those people and I barely know how to search for stuff like this. @this_guy

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Ya, it's possible [**DEMO HERE**](http://jsfiddle.net/BpUHG/1/)

**HTML**

```
<input type="text" class="text-line" />
```

**CSS**

```
body {
    background: #333333;
}
.text-line {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #eeeeee;
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Yes it is possible

HTML

```
<input type="text"/>
```

CSS

```
input[type="text"] {

       border:none; /* Get rid of the browser's styling */
       border-bottom:1px solid black; /* Add your own border */

    }
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/markob83/gBJ2n/)

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with no images and an underline limited to the width of the input, but it'll require a number of CSS properties.  See this: http://jsfiddle.net/2jJvF/

The CSS I used was this:

```
* {
    background-color: black;
}
input[type=text] {
    color: white;
    border: none;
}
input[type=text]:focus {
    outline: none;
}
.text-container {
    border: 0px 1px 0px 0px;
    border-bottom: white solid;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you can create text box then set the background propety to a image which has a horizontal line.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<style>
.body1
{
background-image:url('gradient2.png');

  background-repeat:repeat-y;
  padding-left:20px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>

<input type="text" class="body1" />
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
.text-input {
border-bottom: solid 1px black;
border-top: none;
border-left: none;
border-right: none;    
}
input[type="text"]:focus{

outline: none;

}
```

check my jsfiddle
http://jsfiddle.net/inked/kCXh5/

Answer (score 0):

I have individually tried the 1st and 3rd methods but didn't work. When I tried them together, it worked for me. This is, of course, a copy from the above but this is what it looks like.

```
input[type="text"] {

       border:none; /* Get rid of the browser's styling */
       border-bottom:1px solid black; /* Add your own border */

    }

.text-line {
    background-color: transparent;
    color: #eeeeee;
    outline: none;
    outline-style: none;
    border-top: none;
    border-left: none;
    border-right: none;
    border-bottom: solid #eeeeee 1px;
    padding: 3px 10px;
}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<h2>Card</h2>
<div class="card">
  <div class="container">
    <h4><b>Question</b></h4> 
    <input type="text" class="text-line"/>
    <p>Architect & Engineer</p> 
  </div>
</div>
</body>
```